# Getting Error Code 503 : With authorization header

Tags: angular, rest, http-headers, authorization

I am facing an issue in angular, on hitting API.
Without authorization header I am able to get the response using postman but on adding authorization header I am getting 503 error.

However I cannot remove this header since this is inbuilt in my application.

Comment: Did you check your server side code if it is returning 503 with invalid authorization header.